# Javascript popup link in php

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

i have this php code:

```
echo "<div class='show-popup'><a class='button-popup-container-right' href='javascript:apri('popup.html');' target='_blank'><i class='far fa-play-circle'></i>&nbsp;ASCOLTA LA RADIO</span></a></div>"
```

but, when i click on the link the path is only "javascript:apri("

I have inserted this script in the footer of the page

```
function apri(url) { 
    newin = window.open(url,'Player','top=50, left=50,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=400,height=550,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,nomenubar=no');
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Escape the inner quotes `href='javascript:apri(\'popup.html\');'`

Comment: Also `javascript:` is NOT recommended. Use onclick, or better, data-attributes

Comment: @mplungjan — ```\``` is not an escape character in HTML … and will be consumed by the PHP engine anyway, so that will make no difference.

Comment: @mplungjan — Doesn't matter. The problem is at the HTML level. The ```\``` would never reach the JS parser.

Comment: Anyway. Suggestion: `echo "<div class='show-popup'><a class='button-popup-container-right' href='popup.html' onclick='return apri(this)' target='_blank'><i class='far fa-play-circle'></i>&nbsp;ASCOLTA LA RADIO</span></a></div>";` using `function apri(link) { var w = window.open(this.href); return w?false:true}`

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> href='javascript:apri('
> ```

The first `'` marks the start of the attribute value. The second `'` marks the end of the attribute value.

If you want to include `'` as data then you need to either use `"` to delimit the attribute value or to escape the `'` as `&apos;`.

You can avoid this problem by writing [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and binding your event handlers with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).